# Bayesian predictions

Tags: bayesian, prediction

I have a more general query about some confusion ive been having lately deciding what the bayesian predictions are in my model. Suppose I have a model, $y_{j} = \mu_{j} + e_{j}$, (for which i have observed values $y_j$). I ran a bayesian approach, for which i have priors on $e_j$ and $\mu_j$. My data is distributed $y_j \sim N(\mu_j,e_j)$. If i were to simulate from the posterior distribution for $y_j$ (the posterior predictive distribution, conditioned on the data) using random number generator in RStan during the run, then is it correct to assume that these are my predictions for $y_j$. Or are my predicted values in fact the posterior predicted value for $\mu_j$ ? So, say if i wanted to plot observed vs predicted values, which quantity of the two (posterior mean for $\mu_j$ or posterior predictive distribution for $y_j$ from a random number generator $N(\mu_j,e_j)$) would make more sense to plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When simulating, you can expect *any values that are possible* under the model. When making predictions you are usually interested in *most likely* values given the model. So it depends if you want to explore some possible contractual scenarios, or get *the* prediction right away (then you would take posterior mean, median, mode etc. depending on your needs). [In this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/298242/35989) you can find example of predictions vs simulation from regression model.